# OpenID login not quite working

Tags: python, html, google-app-engine, authentication, openid

So am trying to make my own openID login for my GAE app and I am having a little problem.  It runs fine when I run it on my localhost but then it doesn't run when I try t deploy it.  I assume that is because it doesn't actually try to reach the openID server on my localhost.

Here is my error:

```
File "/base/data/home/apps/s~exployretrial/1.359795154076948420/blog.py", line 97, in get
    providerlist.append(users.create_login_url(federated_identity=uri))
  File "/base/python27_runtime/python27_lib/versions/1/google/appengine/api/users.py", line 246, in create_login_url
    req.set_federated_identity(federated_identity)
  File "cpp_message.pyx", line 124, in cpp_message.SetScalarAccessors.Setter (third_party/apphosting/python/protobuf/proto1/cpp_message.cc:2229)
TypeError: <type 'tuple'> has type <type 'tuple'>, but expected one of: str, unicode
```

Here is my python code:

```
providers = {
    'Google'   : 'www.google.com/accounts/o8/id', # shorter alternative: "Gmail.com"
    'Yahoo'    : 'yahoo.com',
    'MySpace'  : 'myspace.com',
    'AOL'      : 'aol.com',
    'MyOpenID' : 'myopenid.com'
    # add more here
}

class Login(BlogHandler):
    def get(self):
        user = users.get_current_user()
        providerlist = []
        if user:  # signed in already
            self.redirect('/home')
        else:     # let user choose authenticator
            for uri in providers.items():
                providerlist.append(users.create_login_url(federated_identity=uri))
            self.render('login.html', user = user, providerlist = providerlist)
```

HTML Code:

```
<ul>
{% for provider in providerlist %}
  {% if loop.index == 1 %}
    <li><a href="{{ provider }}"><img src="http://openid.net/wordpress-content/uploads/2007/10/aol.png"></a></li>
{% elif loop.index == 2 %}
    <li><a href="{{ provider }}"><img src="http://openid.net/images/get-logos/google.png"></a></li>
{% elif loop.index == 3 %}
    <li><a href="{{ provider }}"><img src="http://openid.net/wordpress-content/uploads/2009/11/yahoo.png"></a></li>
{% elif loop.index == 4 %}
    <li><a href="{{ provider }}"><img src="http://openid.net/images/get-logos/myopenid.png"></a></li>
{% elif loop.index == 5 %}
    <li><a href="{{ provider }}"><img src="http://openid.net/wordpress-content/uploads/2007/10/logo_myspace_s.gif"></a></li>
{% endif %}
{% endfor %}
</ul>
```

So any insight would be greatly appreciated and just let me know if you need more info.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From the Application settings on GAE change the `Authentication Options` to `(Experimental) Federated Login` instead of `Google Accounts API`.

Comment: I've done that and I've gotten it to work when I do a simple python script not using any HTML but I just want it to look decent with logos and everything.

Comment: @clifgray hmm.. You could make it look a bit better if try to integrate this plugin: http://code.google.com/p/openid-selector/